# User needs to click twice for me to get Offline + Gmail access

Tags: javascript, gmail, gmail-api

I'm using javascript to get id token from the user and want offline access as well as access to his gmail info. The problem is the popup window only shows gmail and basic info authorizations. The offline authorizaton  popup will only show after clicking on the button again. Clicking on the button after that will keep giving the offline popup. Why can't I have them all in one window? Or how can I at least get them to popup both at the same time?

This is my code:

```
   function start() {
            gapi.load('auth2', function () {
                auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                    client_id: ' ',
                }).then(function () {              
                    auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                    if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
                       window.location.href = "ClientHome.aspx";
                    }
                });
            });
        }
      function LogIn() {
            auth2.grantOfflineAccess({ redirect_uri: 'postmessage', approval_prompt: 'force', scope: 'https://mail.google.com/', include_granted_scopes: 'true' }).then(signInCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Requests to the Gmail API must be authorized using  [OAuth2.0](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server#using_oauth_20_credentials) credentials  [Offline access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline). You should use server side flow when your application needs access Google APIs on behalf of the user. This approach requires passing a one time authorization code from your client to your server. It acquire an access token and refresh tokens for your server. Access token is passed to the Gmail API to grant your application access to user data.

The following code samples demonstrate exchanging an authorization code for an access token with offline access and storing the refresh token.

```
def get_authorization_url(email_address, state):
"""Retrieve the authorization URL.

Args:
email_address: User's e-mail address.
state: State for the authorization URL.
Returns:
Authorization URL to redirect the user to.
"""
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION, ' '.join(SCOPES))
flow.params['access_type'] = 'offline'
flow.params['approval_prompt'] = 'force'
flow.params['user_id'] = email_address
flow.params['state'] = state
return flow.step1_get_authorize_url(REDIRECT_URI)


def get_credentials(authorization_code, state):
"""Retrieve credentials using the provided authorization code.

email_address = ''
try:
credentials = exchange_code(authorization_code)
user_info = get_user_info(credentials)
email_address = user_info.get('email')
user_id = user_info.get('id')
if credentials.refresh_token is not None:
store_credentials(user_id, credentials)
return credentials
else:
credentials = get_stored_credentials(user_id)
if credentials and credentials.refresh_token is not None:
return credentials
except CodeExchangeException, error:
logging.error('An error occurred during code exchange.')
# Drive apps should try to retrieve the user and credentials for the   current
# ses
```

Comment: No you see I have everything else working I can retrieve the ID to get access and refresh token server side , my problem is client side , the client needs to click TWICE on the button to confirm both gmail and offline access which is not practical

Comment: @JustAway i'm facing same issue, do you fixed it yet or not?